# MySQL query of Hotel database

Tags: mysql

[image]
How to  List the room numbers that are ‘currently’ occupied at Holiday Inn Express.

I wrote the MySQL query ,but I don't get any output. Can anyone help to solve this?

```
SELECT r.rm_number
FROM   hotel h,
       reservation rr,
       room_booking b,
       room r
WHERE  rr.res_id = b.res_id
       AND b.rm_id = r.rm_id
       AND r.htl_id = h.htl_id
       AND h.htl_name = 'Holiday Inn Express'
       AND rr.res_checkin <= CURRENT_DATE
       AND rr.res_checkout >= CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: How do you know there are any data matching your search criteria?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT r.rm_number
FROM   hotel h,
     reservation rr,
     room_booking b,
     room r
WHERE  rr.res_id = b.res_id
     AND b.rm_id = r.rm_id
     AND r.htl_id = h.htl_id
     AND h.htl_name = 'Holiday Inn Express'
     AND rr.res_checkin IS NOT NULL
     AND rr.res_checkout IS NULL ;
```

Comment: It's incorrect to use cross join here.